# Transaction submit error

Tags: testnet

Is there anything wrong with

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --tx-in 2b67b1d3cbab8004f469a2a2f260738704810744350119d75079d7b6f4b1842a#0 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+100000000 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+997320350 \
    --invalid-hereafter 53808126 \
    --fee 1679650 \
    --out-file tx.raw
```

because I'm getting

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 0 (fromList [])) (Value 20000000 (fromList []))))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (BadInputsUTxO (fromList [TxInCompact (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "4e3a6e7fdcb0d0efa17bf79c13aed2b4cb9baf37fb1aa2e39553d5bd720c5c99"}) 4])))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 168273) (Coin 167965)))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (OutsideValidityIntervalUTxO (ValidityInterval {invalidBefore = SNothing, invalidHereafter = SJust (SlotNo 369400)}) (SlotNo 53808413))))])
```

My math might be off. I have a billion test LoveLace in that address.

Update:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --tx-in 2b67b1d3cbab8004f469a2a2f260738704810744350119d75079d7b6f4b1842a#0 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+100000000 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+899823103 \
    --invalid-hereafter 54208180 \
    --fee 176897 \
    --out-file tx.raw
```

still doesn't work:

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 168273) (Coin 167965)))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (OutsideValidityIntervalUTxO (ValidityInterval {invalidBefore = SNothing, invalidHereafter = SJust (SlotNo 53808126)}) (SlotNo 54205604))))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trx has `--fee 1679650`

In the error it notes:

> FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 168273) (Coin 167965))

Note (Coin 167965) is similar to the fee of 1679650. Could there be a typo somewhere?

Probably good to re-calc the fee amount.

Also, what is the balance of UTxO 2b67b1d3cbab8004f469a2a2f260738704810744350119d75079d7b6f4b1842a#0 ?

To match your trx outputs and fee it should be: 1,099,000,000

If you have 1billion exactly then change:

`--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+997320350` to

`--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+898320350` so that it balances.

Comment: I have 1000000000 lovelace + TxOutDatumNone.

Comment: Still doesn't work:

`cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    
--tx-in 2b67b1d3cbab8004f469a2a2f260738704810744350119d75079d7b6f4b1842a#0 \
    
--tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+100000000 \
    
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+898320350 \
    
--invalid-hereafter 53808126 \
    
--fee 167965 \
    
--out-file tx.raw`

Comment: It keeps mentioning 167965 even though I put the zero at the end.

Comment: 1) Your comment notes a diff fee of '--fee 167965' - this then changes the amount for --tx-out but you did not update that value.  Your amounts have to balance eg --tx-in amount = (--tx-out amount + --tx-out amount + --fee amount) 2) Re-calculate the fee to ensure the correct amount to use eg 'cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee ....' 
3) You need to also increase the '--invalid-hereafter' value to beyond the latest maximum testnet slot, check the latest value here https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en.html and add about 500 to it.

Comment: 4) After doing the above can you then post the command used and error message received.

Refer to this guide to construct a simple trx:  https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-simple-transaction/

Comment: Please check update.

Comment: First let's confirm that your local node is 100% synced. Try the command `cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063` . Note the "syncProgress" value. Also note the 'slot' value and use that plus 10000 as your '--invalid-hereafter' value.

Comment: What CLI version are you using? Try `cardano-cli --version` . Also, try adding `--alonzo-era` if on the latest version.

Comment: The error still notes 'FeeTooSmallUTxO' - can you copy/paste to your question the full steps taken to calculate the fee. Too much detail is better than not enough.

Comment: Also, remove file tx.raw to ensure it gets re-created during your steps, and copy/paste in your 'submit' command too so we can see everything that is taking place, thanks.

Comment: I've been giving https://forum.cardano.org/t/how-to-set-up-a-pool-in-a-few-minutes-and-register-using-cntools/48767 a shot. Is there another way to get tAda outside the official faucet since it only lets you get some once a day?

Comment: How much tADA do you need for testing with?
If you need a heap of tADA you could ask on Cardano discord for tADA donations from people.

Answer (score 1):

The slot# error is because the transaction expired - the error indicates you submitted an expired transaction.

Use the higher fee as you did in the second tx, as well as a larger slot expiration. Set the `--invalid-hereafter` to 60000000 and let it rip!